# Assign query type on typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I can't solve this, this work as I want but I can't compile it. What is the problem?

```js
const knownQueries = <const>{
    query: {
        layerToken: 'layer-token'
    },
    test: {
        tId: 'id',
    }
}

type KnownQueries = typeof knownQueries
type KnownQueryPrimaryKey = keyof KnownQueries
type KnownQueryKey<P extends KnownQueryPrimaryKey> = keyof KnownQueries[P]
type KnownQueryResult<P extends KnownQueryPrimaryKey, K extends KnownQueryKey<P>> = KnownQueries[P][K]

type BodyRequestQuery = {
    [P in KnownQueryPrimaryKey]?: boolean | { [K in KnownQueryKey<P>]?: boolean }
}

type BodyRequestValue = string | number | boolean | { [key: string]: BodyRequestValue }

type BodyRequest<T extends BodyRequestQuery> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        [V in keyof T[K]as T[K][V] extends true ? KnownQueryResult<K, V> : never]: BodyRequestValue // PROBLEM HERE with "KnownQueryResult<K, V>"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Type 'T[K][V] extends true ? KnownQueryResult<K, V> : never' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
Type 'KnownQueryResult<K, V>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
```

Comment: What do these types do?

Comment: Can you give an example on how your objects will look like? How does a BodyRequest look like? This looks really complicated and I wonder how did you get here.

Comment: BodyRequest is the response from query. Query = { query: {layerToken: true } }, and result should be "{ query: { 'layer-token': BodyRequestValue }}", this 'extract' properties from object according to query. I want to query as KnownQueryKey keys and get a result as knownQueries (layerToken to 'layer-token' key as example)

Comment: @BrunoMarotta like syntax error